# Azure CloudStorageAccount Android : Acces blob from android

Tags: android, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

We're trying to access azure blob storage from a java client application (Android).
This is explained in following tutorial: Tutorial Blob Java

We're getting an exception when starting application from eclipse.
"could not find method javax.xml.stream.xmlinputfactory.newinstance referenced from method com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.utility.createXMLstreamReaderFromReader".

It seems that azure is using XML Library that does not exist in android.

Below a code snippet:

```
public static final String storageConnectionString = 
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" + 
        "AccountName=myaccountname;" + 
        "AccountKey=myaccountkey";

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FileOutputStream FileXml = null;
    // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        // Create the blob client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        // Get a reference to a container
        // The container name must be lower case
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("weetjesandroid");
```

Comment: Why do you access blob from Android and expose your account key inside the app? It should be at server side. Since you may have multiple client apps to store items in blob storage, it is best to keep that at server side. You can use host this as WebAPI service and call from different clients.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use Android's [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to directly access the [Blob Service REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx).

Read [Authentication for the Windows Azure Storage Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx) to understand how to provide the required `Authorization` request header.

You'll have to write more code and understand how to call the required APIs but I can attest this approach works.

Comment: I have accessed a public blob via this command, http://accountName.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName/BlobName.xml.

I tried also to access a private blob via this command, without success:
http://portalvhdsqlt2gqj2g4vw7.blob.core.windows.net/weetjesandroidsecured/BlobAzureWeetjes1.xml HTTP/1.
Authorization="SharedKey AccountName:PrimaryKeyAzure"
x-ms-date: Tue, 17 Aug 2010 21:41:56 GMT
What should i change in order to get it work.

Comment: @JVGAG, maybe your comment got truncated. What are showing are not commands, only URLs. I suggest you update your question with the code you used for these commands. And, have you used HttpURLConnection as suggested?